# How to check for the word of the day

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, constants

I need help figuring this out

I need to:

> write a JavaScript function named ‘checkWordOfTheDay’ which accepts a single parameter for a word. Compare the parameter to a const value containing a word of your choosing. Return true if the parameter matches the word, and false if it doesn’t.
>   Write unit tests in tests.js to test the checkWordOfTheDay function and ensure that they function correctly by running the UnitTests.html page and confirming the result
>   On the home page, add an input field and a button where the user can guess the word of the day. Display an alert letting them know if they guessed correctly or not.

This is what I have so far for my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var word = "cat";
    function checkWordOfTheDay(word);
});
```

Comment: Sounds a lot like homework. The code you present is just a template, which might well have been provided with the assignment. You should at least try to solve the assignment and then come back with a particular issue you bump into.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are assuming to have loaded jQuery (the `$` function).

This might not be needed.

To declare a function in js you can simply:

```
function nameOfTheFunction(parameter) {
...
}
```

and inside the function you can check the value of the parameter against a constant of your choosing.

There is a lot here to understand, so I'll suggest to start here and only later move to the test (Which are basically functions that call your function and check the expected results).

[Might be worth reading](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)